# How to pass string data type to number datatype in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-01722, ora-01403

I have procedure like this...

```
declare
v_psg varchar2(10);
id_no number;

begin

select value into v_psg from settings_am where key = 'PSG';
select id into id_no from product where to_char(psg) in (v_psg);
end;`
```

The value returned  from `select value into v_psg from settings_am where key = 'PSG';` would be

> '1','2','3'

when i run this procedure i am returned with ora error - ORA-01403.

please advise how i should pass the v_psg value to psg column of product table?

[EDIT - Tried with test case suggested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2hCa.png)

Comment: At least, One of your SQL statements cannot find what it's looking for from related tables. Consider applying exception handling against no_data_found exception.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `to_char(psg)` makes no sense whatsoever as the column `psg` is already a `varchar`

Comment: No it is not, column value from table settings is varchar2 where as the column psg from table product is number.

Answer (score 1):

If you got `ORA-01403`, you were kind of *lucky*. It is the `NO_DATA_FOUND` error, which means that one (probably the first) query didn't return anything.

Those two statements could be combined into

```
select id 
from product
where to_char(psg) in (select value 
                       from settings_am 
                       where key = 'PSG'
                      );
```

Why would you select `value` first, and then use it in another query? Besides, it just wouldn't work. `v_psg` is declared as `VARCHAR2` variable. The way you described it, it contains the following string: `'1','2','3'`, as if this is what you have:

```
SQL> create table settings_am (key  varchar2(10),
  2                            value varchar2(20));    --> note size here

Table created.

SQL> insert into settings_am (key, value)
  2    values ('PSG', q'['1','2','3']');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From settings_am;

KEY        VALUE
---------- --------------------
PSG        '1','2','3'

SQL>
```

As you can see, I enlarged the `value` column size, although variable you declared says `10`. Why? Because of

```
SQL> select length(value) from settings_am where key = 'PSG';

LENGTH(VALUE)
-------------
           11
```

i.e. you can't put something that is long *11* into something that accepts length *10*.

Or, if your data actually contains 3 rows for the `PSG` key, are those values already enclosed into single quotes? If so, that's strange; people usually don't do that. Anyway, suppose that you managed to get string `'1,2,3'` (which is what I presume you actually have) into a `VARCHAR2` variable, then you have to split it into rows in order to be able to use it in the `IN` clause:

```
SQL> create table product (id number, psg varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into product (id, psg) values (100, '1');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into product (id, psg) values (200, '2');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Query is then (where lines #3 - 5 represent splitting a string into rows):

```
SQL> select p.id
  2  from product p
  3  where p.psg in (select regexp_substr('&&v_psg', '[^,]+', 1, level)
  4                  from dual
  5                  connect by level <= regexp_count('&&v_psg', ',') + 1
  6                 );
Enter value for v_psg: 1,2,3

        ID
----------
       100
       200
```

So, wouldn't it be simpler to use

```
SQL> select id
  2  from product
  3  where to_char(psg) in (select value
  4                         from settings_am
  5                         where key = 'PSG'
  6                        );

        ID
----------
       100
       200

SQL>
```

Note that both options also show why your query is wrong: you can't put two values (rows) into a variable declared as `id_no number;` as you'd get `TOO_MANY_ROWS` error.

---

Finally, what is it that you'd want to do? What problem are you trying to solve? Apparently, except for special cases (only one row for each value) your query can't work. If you could provide test case (create table & insert into sample data), as well as expected output, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: the data you had prepared seems absolutely fine  but when i tried to pass query under "in" statement `select * from product where to_char(id) in (select value from settings_am where key = 'PSG')` it returns "0" rows. i had the results returned using regex but i was looking for a better solution hence posted the question. although i see the results returned for you with test data not sure why am returned with 0 rows.

Comment: As I said: prepare test case. Meanwhile, check `value` datatype. If it is `CHAR`, note that it is right padded with spaces up to its full length, so you might need to `trim(value)`.

Comment: the test case you built is perfectly fine so i have not made up anything myself. further i copy pasted your scripts for tables creation/select statements and observed am returned with 0 rows where as the expected result is 2 rows.

Comment: I know that my test case is OK. It is **your data** I'm interested in.

Comment: my data is exact replica of your test case there is no difference, whatsoever. having said that, i had used your test case and still do not get the result same as you. i had edited my post and added an image for you to understand.